# Homology relative to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to prove $$ \widetilde{ H_n}(X)\cong H_n(X, \ast)$$

The long exact sequence for pairs gives me $H_n(X) = \widetilde{H_n}(X) \cong H_n(X, \ast)$ for $n>0$

and $\widetilde{H_0}(X) \cong \widetilde{H_0}(X, \ast) $.

So I would like to show $\widetilde{H_0} (X, \ast) \cong H_0(X, \ast) $ to finish my proof.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of $\tilde{H}_n(X)$?

Comment: The homology groups that come from the extended chain complex where one inserts $\mathbb{Z}$ at the end of the sequence. (the definition in Hatcher)

Comment: Try to prove, that the relative chain complex $C(X,*)$ and the extended chain complex $\tilde C(X)$ are chain homotopic.

Comment: Here is another way to look at the situation at hand: $i: (pt,\emptyset) \to (X,\emptyset)$ and $j: (X,\emptyset) \to (X,pt)$ give rise to a short exact sequence $E: \quad 0 \to C(pt) \to C(X), \to C(X,pt) \to 0$. The augmentation map $\epsilon : C_0(X) \to \mathbb Z \cong C_0(pt)$ then defines a left splitting of $E$.

Comment: Yet another way - use the end of the augmented chain complex $\cdots \to C_2(X) \to C_1(X) \to C_0(X) \stackrel{\delta}{\to} C_{-1}(X) \to 0$ to get the short exact sequence $0 \to \ker \delta \to C_0(X) \to C_{-1}(X) \to 0$, show $C_{-1}(X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and hence the sequence splits, and then use this to show what you desire

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here: $0 \rightarrow C_0(\ast) \xrightarrow{i} C_0(X) \xrightarrow{j} C_0(X, \ast ) \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} 0$.

Comment: @Matt: Where did you get that sequence? Try using one of the sequences above - you should get a (split) five term short exact sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my third comment: The splitting defines an isomorphism $C(X) \cong C(X,*) \oplus C(*)$ with projections $\epsilon$ and $j$ and inclusion $i$. Using this identification we arrive at the following situation, where all the maps are the evident projections and inclusions:

$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\tilde C_1(X) & \stackrel{p_{1}}{\cong} & C_1(X,*) & \stackrel{q_{1}}{\cong} & \tilde C_1(X) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\tilde C_0(X) \cong C_0(X,*) \oplus \mathbb Z & \stackrel{p_{0}}{\to} & C_0(X,*) & \stackrel{q_{0}}{\to}  & C_0(X,*) \oplus \mathbb Z \cong \tilde C_0(X)\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\mathbb Z & \stackrel{p_{-1}}{\to} & 0 & \stackrel{q_{-1}}{\to} & \mathbb Z

\end{array}$$

It should now be easy to see that $h: \tilde C(X) \to \tilde C(X)^{+1}$, given by the inclusion $h_{-1}: \mathbb Z \to C_0(X,*) \oplus \mathbb Z$ and $h_k = 0$ otherwise, defines a chain homotopy of the horizontal map $q_* \circ p_*$ in the diagram above and the identity map on $\tilde C(X)$. On the other hand we have $p_* \circ q_* = id_{C(X,*)}$, which proves $C(X,*)$ and $\tilde C(X)$ to be chain homotopy equivalent.

Comment: thanks! I understand that $0 \rightarrow C(\ast) \xrightarrow{i_\ast} C_0(X) \xrightarrow{j_\ast} C_0(X, \ast) \rightarrow 0$ splits because $i_\ast$ has an inverse (the constant map is a left inverse). From that it follows that $C_0(X) \cong   C_0(X, \ast) \oplus C_0(\ast )$. 
How did you get $\tilde{C_0} (X) \cong C_0(X, \ast) \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cong C_0(X, \ast)  \oplus C_0(\ast)$ from that?

Comment: No the left inverse is the augmentation map $\epsilon$ in dimension $0$ and constant map otherwise. Note that $\tilde C_k(X) = C_k(X)$ for all $k \geq 0$ and $\tilde C_{-1}(X) = \mathbb Z$ by definition.

Comment: But the augmentation map is at the end of the chain, like so: $0 \rightarrow C(\ast) \xrightarrow{i_\ast} C_0(X) \xrightarrow{j_\ast} C_0(X, \ast) \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ so how can it be an inverse for $i_\ast$?

Comment: $\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \to & C_0(\ast) & \stackrel{i_\ast}{\to} & C_0(X) & \to & C_0(X,\ast) & \to & 0 \\
 & & \Arrowvert & & \Arrowvert & & & & \\
 &  & C_0(\ast)\cong \mathbb Z & \stackrel{\varepsilon}{\leftarrow} & C_0(X) & & & &
\end{array}$

Comment: While I don't know how to typeset this correctly...

Comment: @AlexanderThumm, can I ask you somethng to check that I'm understanding? To conclude equality at $n=0$, you are using  $0 \to C(*) \to C(X) \to C(X, *) \to 0$ is a SEC, and studying it at level zero?

Comment: I'm not seeing why we can't we can't extend the splitting $\epsilon:C_0(X)\to C_0(*)$ to one from $\epsilon: C_n(X)\to C_n(*)$ by the same formula since $C_n(*)$ can still be canonically identified with $\mathbb{Z}$ as all maps into a point are constant. But this would yield an isomorphism $C_n(X)\cong C_n(*)\oplus C_n(X,*)$ which means your $p_i,q_i$ will not be isomorphisms for $i\geq 1$, but rather look like the case when $i=0$.